# Habilitar horário no datapicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datapicker

Estou usando o boostrap-material-datetimepicker.js que como resultado segue abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O único problema é que quando altero a linha abaixo:

```
minDate: moment().endOf('day')
```

Ele desabilita também o horário conforme a figura 2, porém quando coloco:

```
minDate: null
```

Consigo selecionar os horários, mas em compensação, as datas anteriores também ficam desabilitadas.

Como faço para habilitar os horários, mas mantendo as datas anteriores desabilitadas?

Comment: Não há uma contradição aí? `Consigo selecionar os horários, mas em compensação, as datas anteriores também ficam desabilitadas.

Como faço para habilitar os horários, mas mantendo as datas anteriores desabilitadas?`

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você pretende deixar disponível os dias e as horas a partir da dia, horas e minutos no momento, certo?

Se for isso basta utilizar:

```
moment().milliseconds(0);
```

Utilizando `moment().endOf('day')` retorna a data Atual 23:59:59

Comment: Olá pessoal. Realmente acho que não consegui me expressar direito. Na agenda, o usuário não poderá selecionar os dias anteriores ao dia atual. Para isso coloquei `minDate: moment().endOf('day')`, só que quando uso esse comando, acabo desabilitando também os horários e não é isso que quero. Preciso que os horários estejam livres para escolha, independente do dia e os dias anteriores ao dia atual, fiquem desabilitados. Desculpem por não estar conseguindo expor o meu problema de forma compreensível.

Comment: Porque estou usando em sincronia com o fullcalendar, do qual desabilitei os dias anteriores ao dia atual. O usuário então clica em um determinado dia, abre-se um modal com os campos: Titulo, Data Início, Hora Início, Data Final, Hora Final, Agendamento. Os campos Data Início, Hora Início, Data Final e Hora Final estou usando o datapicker conforme a imagem. Mas se o fullcalendar não permite selecionar os dias anteriores ao dia atual, gostaria que o datapicker também tivesse opção, sem interferir na seleção dos horários. Assim a sincronia ficaria completa.